# VS code as a markdown editor for blog website

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, markdown

I created a blog that uses markdown language for articles. I needed a beautiful and fast markdown editor for my website. I found website called
[Readme.so](https://readme.so/editor) which uses vs code to edit readme files. I did not find any information on how they did that.

I would be grateful if you tell me how to implement vs code on the website to edit md files.

Comment: Google Monaco editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [Monaco Editor for React](https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor). It's pretty straightforward to install with preference of your package manager and move forward with it like below.

`yarn add react-monaco-editor`